# Device administrator disabling

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Device administration app can not be uninstalled if it is not
disabled. User can disable "Device Administrators" from the settings.
When company gives android devices to its employees, company wants to
have a control over devices, their statuses and policies, but user can
easily get rid of that control. Does anybody know how it is possible
to prevent user from disabling Device Administrators?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to prevent the user from disabling Device Administrators, at least using the published APIs. The best you can do is disallow programs from running if certain policies aren't in place.

Some manufacturers (e.g., Samsung) have extended the base APIs to allow additional capabilities, but these are not part of the standard Android platform.

Comment: Something else did occur to me though, as I was thinking about what some apps (e.g., WaveSecure) do.  Because the user requesting to disable the Device Administrator is, itself, an Action (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED), you could perhaps do something like locking the device when receiving this Action (assuming the application was installed with this capability).  I'm pretty sure that's what WaveSecure does.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I looked at Wavesecure. They really prevent user from disabling manager, it's actually get disabled, but keep lock activity until password entered. After reboot admin manager is enabled.

Comment: Hey Mark, in WareSecure they pop up "ScreenLocked" activity every time user is trying to run any app? Ideas how they handle other app started event?

Comment: Hmm... not off hand. There's a discussion about the topic going on here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480048/registering-my-broadcast-receiver-to-run-when-an-app-is-launched - and Mark Murphy indicates that there isn't an Intent for this, so there probably isn't :-)

Answer (score 2):

In DeviceAdminReceiver.java you could do something like this onDisableRequested:

```
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getName(), 0);
    String DEVICE_ADMIN_CAN_DEACTIVATE = settings.getString("DEVICE_ADMIN_CAN_DEACTIVATE", null);
    if(DEVICE_ADMIN_CAN_DEACTIVATE.equals("ON")){
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startMain);
        return "OOPS!";
    }else{
        String msg_char_onDisable = context.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_char_onDisable);
        return msg_char_onDisable;
    }
}
```

Comment: When user clicks Deactivate in device admin section it will start Intent to home screen if in app setting is set so and deviceadmin will not be deactivated

Comment: But getSharedPreferences can be cleared by user i guess, so it would be nicer to save that info somewhere else.

Comment: This is Not working on Android 4.1.2. "OOPS!" will pop up ,then after some time Home Screen . .

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to prevent disabling the device administrator.
When the user initiates deactivation and we recieve ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED callback, we re-launch the settings activity intent.

A message is allowed by the OS to be displayed asking for confirmation from the user. According to Android OS rules, for about 5 seconds, no app is allowed to launch on top of this confirmation dialog. So basically the settings activity we tried to open will only launch after 5 seconds.

To pass these 5 seconds without allowing the user to confirm deactivation, the phone is locked by the device administrator repeatedly in a background thread. After 5 seconds when the user unlocks the device, 'Settings' activity will have been restarted.

The following code for Device Admin Broadcast Receiver Class illustrates the above method.

DevAdminReceiver.java

```
public class DevAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    DevicePolicyManager dpm;
    long current_time;
    Timer myThread;

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        Log.d("Root", "Device Owner Enabled");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Device Admin","Disable Requested");
        Intent startMain = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startMain);

        dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        myThread = new Timer();
        current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myThread.schedule(lock_task,0,1000);

        return "Warning";
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            CharSequence res = onDisableRequested(context, intent);
            if (res != null) {
                dpm.lockNow();
                Bundle extras = getResultExtras(true);
                extras.putCharSequence(EXTRA_DISABLE_WARNING, res);
            }
        }else if (ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("Device Admin","Disabled");
        }
    }

    // Repeatedly lock the phone every second for 5 seconds
    TimerTask lock_task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - current_time;
            if (diff<5000) {
                Log.d("Timer","1 second");
                dpm.lockNow();
            }
            else{
                myThread.cancel();
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Ensure `force lock` policy is set for the device admin in the resource file.

This is a purely a workaround and not an intended solution from the side of the developers. Apps which abuse Device Admin permissions are mostly taken down from the Google Play Store when exposed.

Complete sample code having the required Manifest declarations and resource xml file is present in the following repo
https://github.com/abinpaul1/Android-Snippets/tree/master/PermanentDeviceAdministrator