# How to disable the installation of device administrator application?

Tags: android

We can create device administrator application which supposedly have escalated privileges to enforce certain policies like password quality, device encryption etc.

See:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

But for example the device is provisioned the first time by the administrator (administrator install the app for user) and the device is passed to the user, it can be easily disabled (Under Settings -> Security -> Device Administrator) or even uninstalled.

Is there any way this can be prevented? Like a password is required to disable the device administrator?

Can this be done? Is there any other way?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: Answer is probably already outdated, but if you still need it. NO without changing firmware, user is an "admin" on the device and can do what he/she wants.

Comment: You can try some thing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673756/1753157

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that.
Device administrator have to be voluntarily installed by the user.
User decides if he wants to enable device administrator. Usually if device is not having proper device admin installed and enabled, he is being "punished" by the access refusal to e.g. corporate network.