# How to monitoring app swaping in foreground?

Tags: android, foreground

when my application run in background. It need to monitoring others application swaping in the foreground and get their name. How to implement? 
   i.e. When an app goto the foreground. My app must be notified. then gets its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For monitoring other Applications you can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) for getting current top Appliction for Activity Stack as in Your Appliction:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context. ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes1 = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = processes1.get(0).topActivity;
String classname =processes1.get(0).topActivity.getClassName(); 
String packagename = processes1.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

Comment: Thank your for reply. Which broadcast shout to register?

Comment: you just need to add android.permission.GET_TASKS permission in manifest and create an service for watching Activity Stack using ActivityManager.

Comment: Sorry, I still not understand. Should i run above code every second? how to receive the event?

Comment: Yes as i known only activity Manager is a way to check if your which application is interacting with user or not. you need to run your service in background every second but this is power consuming task so start your service on ON_USER_PRESENT Receiver  bez this action fire when user is using mobile after screen lock and stop it when screen is off Using SCREEN_OFF Receiver

Comment: Yes,I can not find other way. maybe it is best.

Answer (score 5):

Accessibility services provide a means to get the current foreground service.

Extend the Accessibility Service and create a new class. Listen for AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED event. This event is triggered whenever the foreground activity is changed. The event object passed with the callback contains the package name of the foreground app.

AccessibilityService.java

```
public class AccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService{
    public static AccessibilityService instance;
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        // Note : This event is sometimes called more than one for a foreground service
        if (accessibilityEvent.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED){
            Log.d("Event","TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED");
            Log.d("Pkg",accessibilityEvent.getPackageName().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d("Accessibility","Service Connected");
    }
}
```

To successfully implement the service the manifest file must also contain the following declaration in the application section along with a config file in the res/xml folder

```
<service android:name=".AccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig"/>
</service>
```

serviceconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />
```

Ensure accessibility services permission are granted by the user. It requires manual enabling from the side of the user.

The complete code for sample app to get the foreground process name is available at https://github.com/abinpaul1/Android-Snippets/tree/master/GetForegroundService

Answer (score 0):

we can’t use getRunningTasks because android specifies “method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces“.

There is no direct approach to get the app status while background or foreground, but there is possibility of getting to know when app is foreground and background
 For more details: [See here](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)